# What determines how PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT works with an ODBC connection?

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, unixodbc

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) for ATTR_TIMEOUT says:

> Specifies the timeout duration in seconds. Not all drivers support
>   this option, and it's meaning may differ from driver to driver. For
>   example, sqlite will wait for up to this time value before giving up
>   on obtaining an writable lock, but other drivers may interpret this as
>   a connect or a read timeout interval.

I am using an ODBC connection via unixODBC to a closed-source database called Vertica, and I am not seeing the proper connection timeout behavior when I connect via:

```php
$this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password,
                      array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                            PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 2));   // timeout in 2 seconds
```

Is that behavior provided by the PDO PHP class, or unixODBC, or the Vertica ODBC driver itself?  Trying to figure out where to start debugging.

Comment: This bug exists from 2008 but it doesn't look like it ever made it into the source tree for PHP: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45287

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this simply by attempting to open a TCP connection to vertica with a timeout (on the correct port), and immediately closing on a successful connection.  While this does not guarantee that I am actually talking to a healthy Vertica database, it is sufficient for my own use case.

Something like this seems to be working OK:

```
protected function isAlive() {
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_nonblock($socket);
    for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
        if(!@socket_connect($socket, $this->host, $this->port)) {
            usleep(100000);                 // sleep for 0.1 seconds
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```